# Counting occurrences of a characters omitting a field

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
hello even evening
how are they?
...
```

I want to count the occurences of the letter e but without taking the letter e of the 1st field under consideration. I've used this command but it doesn't work.

```
awk 'for(i=2;i<=NR;i++) match($i,/e/){sum++}END{print  sum}'
```

Comment: awk uses a pattern { action } syntax. Whatever that for header does, you obviously intended to bracket the whole line in { .. }. Also "it does not work" is inadequate. What does it do, and what did you expect it to do?

Answer (score 5):

With flexible `gsub` feature:

```
awk '{ $1=""; cnt += gsub("e", "") }END{ print cnt }' file
```

> The `gsub()` function returns the number of substitutions made

Comment: thank you so much! what if I wanted to count the occurrences of the letter e per line?

Comment: @user25, to print count per line -  just use `awk '{ $1=""; print gsub("e", "") }' file`

Comment: how could I put the output of the command in a variable? inside the awk?

Comment: @user25 The same way you put the output of any command in a variable: `var=$(awk ...)`

Answer (score 3):

Your loop looks correct apart from using `NR` (number of the current record/line) in place of `NF` (number of fields in the current record/line), but it would be easier to count with `gsub()`:

```
$ awk '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) sum+=gsub("e","e",$i) } END { print sum }' file
6
```

The `gsub()` function returns the number of times it makes a substitution.

In Perl, you would use the `tr` operator in a similar way

```
$ perl -ane 'shift @F; map($sum += tr/e/e/, @F); END { print $sum, "\n" }' file
6
```

Or, you could just use the other basic utilities from the tool chest:

```sh
$ cut -d ' ' -f 2- file | tr -dc 'e' | wc -m
       6
```

This cuts off everything before the first space character, deletes everything that isn't an `e`, and then counts the number of characters that are left.

Answer (score 1):

Some more approaches:

1. coreutils

   ```
   $ cut -d' ' -f 2- file | fold -w1 | grep -c e
   6
   ```
2. Perl (basically a golfed version of what [Kusalananda gave](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/560084/22222))

   ```
   $ perl -lane 'map{$k+=tr/e//}@F[1..$#F];}{print $k ' file
     perl -lane 'map{$k+=s/e/e/g}@F[1..$#F]}{print $k' file
   6
   ```
3. GNU grep + awk (just for fun)

   ```
   $ grep -oP '^\S+\K.*' file | awk -F'e' '{k+=NF-1}END{print k}'
   6
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$ perl -lpe '/\S\s/g;$s+=()=/e/g}{print $s' file
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{sum += gsub(/e/,"&") - gsub(/e/,"&",$1)} END{print sum+0}' file
6
```

Comment: Is there any benefit in using `gsub(/e/,"&")` instead of `gsub(/e/,"")` or is it just habit, and general good practice?

Comment: @terdon In this case if I used "" instead of "&" in the first gsub() then there'd be no `e`s left for the 2nd gsub() to count. I tend to always use `"&"` by default unless I **need** to remove the matched strings so I don't trip myself up if I need to print the original record or do anything else that requires the content to be as read.