# How to store and line up the output of a command in an awk script?

Tags: text-processing, awk, scripting

So, I have an awk script that counts the occurences of a character minus the first field, and I want to store the output of the command in a variable all lined up. However, the following method doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/awk -f
{
var=$($1="";print gsub("o",""))
echo $var
}
```

Input:

```
Hello how are you?
Orange obliviate
```

Output:

```
3
2
```

Desired output:

```
3 2
```

Thank you!

Comment: Some example input with expected output would be welcomed, otherwise it may difficult to understand what you mean by "lined up".  Also, there is no `echo` command in `awk`, nor are there command substitutions.

Comment: @Kusalananda sure please see the edited post

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by storing the numbers in an array that you output in an `END` block:

```awk
{
    $1 = ""
    count[++n] = gsub("o", "")
}

END {
    $0 = ""                   # empty the current record
    for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        $i = count[i]         # create new fields for output

    # output the current record (created above)
    print
}
```

Or, you can output the numbers as you calculate them, separated by the field delimiter if needed, and then finish the line in the `END` block:

```awk
{
    $1 = ""

    # Print the number, preceded by OFS if this is not the first line.
    # Does not output a newline (ORS).
    printf "%s%s", (NR > 1 ? OFS : ""), gsub("o", "")
}

END {
    # Finish the output (ORS is a newline by default).
    printf "%s", ORS
}
```

Both of these variants allow the user to set `OFS` and `ORS` to values appropriate to them on the command line, e.g.

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' -f script.awk file
2,1
```

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' -f script.awk file
2       1
```

```
$ awk -v OFS='-->' -v ORS='.\n' -f script.awk file
2-->1.
```

Note: I'm assuming that the output shown in the question is wrong as it's what you would get when *not* ignoring the first field (and ignoring the case of the `o` *letter*).

Comment: In `gsub` you should use regex to count O caps.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes, if they are interested in doing a case-insensitive count of letters. However, this is not what they use in their code, and besides, they explicitly say "character", not "letter".

Comment: In OP example for second line I see count 2 which mean for me they count letters :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov This is because they are counting the first field. I think this is an error in the question.  In the text, they say they want to skip the first field, and this is also a requirement in [another recent question from the same user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560077).

Comment: @kasulananda. Can't have it both ways. Their first data line has 1 lower-case o in the first field and two others, and their second line has zero lower-case o in the first field and one other. So what he is claiming as actual output cannot be true.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant The "desired output" is inconsistent with the text earlier in the question in any case.